# can't turn off warning while calling vba from another workbook

Tags: excel

this issue is really driving me nuts. I have two workbooks with macro that one will wake up in the morning and open up another macro to download the roster.

my problem is the prompt to ask me if I want to save my files cannot be gone away.
as you can see I turn off all sort of alerts in beginning of both vba workbook.

if I would have run only the one, I can run it without the 'do you want to save' warning.
if I would call another workbook, then the error message appear. anyway to disable it while the script is being called from another workbook?

Workbook to call another vba

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.Run "'Roster_Compare.xlsm'!Open_Roster"
```

Workbook to download and calculate roster

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
'download data and do some calculation script here
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Data_Path & "\Roster_" & Date1 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWindow.Close
```

error i have click to move on

[book1 as example, file already saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThSch.png)

Comment: Can't recreate the symptom. Suggest moving `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to immediately above `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` and retest. This will at least establish if somewhere in the preceding processes, Alerts are being turned back on. Also, it's just better practice to turn off Alerts as close to the code they are being turned off for, and then turn back on immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to:  `ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: i tried but still the same.